# json.dump(list, f) keeps on loading on Google Colab

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I am trying to perform json.dump operation as below on Google Colab. However, everytime it gets stuck and keep processing this line only. How to solve this issue in google colab ?

```
with open(fullpath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list, f)
```

EDIT: Adding the complete code:

```
import generate_gt_from_txt_l
import generate_gt_from_xml_l

#We've shown words are identical for txt and xml so don't do both
import generate_gt_from_txt_w

import load_set
import json
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sets = load_set.load()
    set_names = ['training', 'val1', 'val2', 'test']

    generators = [generate_gt_from_txt_l, generate_gt_from_xml_l, generate_gt_from_txt_w]
    gen_paths = ['lines/txt', 'lines/xml', 'words']

    for s_name, s in zip(set_names, sets):
        for g_path, g in zip(gen_paths, generators):
            fullpath = os.path.join("raw_gts", g_path, s_name+'.json')
            try:
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fullpath))
            except:
                pass
            print(type(g.get_gt(s)))
            with open(fullpath, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(g.get_gt(s), f)
            print(fullpath)
```

The code runs fine when I run it on my system. It just causes issues on Colab.

Comment: What is the content of `list`? What is `fullpath`? Seeing the full code could help us

Comment: Try doing `data = g.get_gt(s)` and then dumping this data to a JSON file. Add print/debug statement at each step. Maybe your code is stuck in `get_gs`

Comment: No the code is not stuck on that. It runs fine on my system

Comment: I'm suspecting that when you call 'type(g.get_gs(s))', you are emptying this generator or causing it to wait.

Comment: The thing is, we need a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you

Comment: @BeChillerToo no. I added the type check later to see whether it was returning the correct datatype or not.

Comment: See what I am trying to say is, I am facing all these issues only on Colab, works perfectly on my system. So the code is fine. Is it something that has to be done specifically in colab ?

Comment: @TavishJain that may be the case, but we cannot verify what the code does in its current state, we can only take your word for it that it works on your machine. What is returned by `load_sets()`? What are these `generators` actually doing? What does `get_gt(s)` do?

Comment: @C.Nivs generators are custom scripts of mine. get_gt(s) retrives items from them

Comment: Is it possible that `g.get_gt(s)` just takes a long time? I'd highly recommend writing a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing the minimum amount of code needed to run and reproduce the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the name of your variable `list`: `list` is already used by Python

Comment: the original variable name is something else. it is an example here

Comment: How did you declare that variable then?